# how to insert records from one table to another selecting only the common columns

Tags: sql, oracle, select

i want to insert records from one table to another with common columns

```
desc fp_mast        null?     type

emp_id              not null  varchar2(4) 
emp_nm              not null  varchar2(35) 
typ                 not null  varchar2(1) 
flag                not null  varchar2(1) 
st_dt               not null  DATE 
end_dt                        DATE
wk_dt               not null  DATE
```

desc emp_mast           null?     type

```
emp_id              not null  varchar2(4) 
emp_nm              not null  varchar2(35) 
grd_cd              not null  varchar2(3) 
desg_cd             not null  varchar2(2) 
cost_sl             not null  varchar2(2)                 
flag                not null  varchar2(1) 
join_dt             not null  DATE 
resig_dt                      DATE
wk_dt               not null  DATE
```

i tried this query to insert the records but did not work

```
insert into fp_mast(emp_id,emp_nm,st_dt,end_dt,wk_dt)
select(emp_no,emp_nm,join_dt,resig_dt,wk_dt)
from emp_mast
where emp_id in ('7996','7942','5251','7999','8249','6464','8220',
'8221')
```

it kept showing me the following error

missing right parenthesis

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> missing right parenthesis

Because you have a syntax error in the **SELECT** statement.

Change this:

```
select(emp_no,emp_nm,join_dt,resig_dt,wk_dt)
```

to this:

```
select emp_no,emp_nm,join_dt,resig_dt,wk_dt
```

You don't need the **parenthesis** for the column names in the select list. I think you got confused with the way **VALUES** keyword is used.

Comment: i changed the query and removed the brackets and its now showing me this error

SQL> `insert into fp_mast(EMP_ID,EMP_NM,ST_DT,END_DT,WK_DT)
  2  select EMP_ID,emp_nm,join_dt,resig_dt,wk_dt
  3  from emp_mast
  4  where emp_id in ('7996','7942','5251','7999','8249','6464',
  5  '8220','8221','8220','7106','7220','7187','8183','7423',
  6  '8192','8184','8219','8070','8120','8053'
  7  ,'8033','8154')
  8  /`
insert into fp_mast(EMP_ID,EMP_NM,ST_DT,END_DT,WK_DT)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("AGROVET"."FP_MAST"."TYP")
`

SQL>

Comment: the columns mentioned ("AGROVET"."FP_MAST"."TYP"), must have not null constraints on them, and as you are not inserting anything into them you get this error.